# How to show all users, including IP, rank and other variables?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am a starting PHP/sql-programmer, I am making a dashboard just for learning and I have a question. I want to let the page show something like this:

**ID**  **Name**     **IP**            **Rank**
1   Willem    127.0.0.1  5
2   You       127.0.0.1  3

```
<table style="width:100%;color:white;">
          <tr>
            <th><center>ID</center></th><th>Naam:</th><th>IP:</th><th><center>Actie</center></th>
          </tr> <?php 
          $d = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000");
          while($r = $d->fetch_object()){ 
          ?>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:35px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $r->id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r->userName; ?></td>
            <td><font color="red">Geblokkeerd</font></td>
            <td style="width:50px;text-align:center"><a href="./ase_users?type=edit&id=<?php echo $r->id; ?>">Bewerk</a></td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>
        </table
```

But if I put this code in de page, it gives me the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: conn in /home/xxxxxxx/domains/xxxxxxx.nl/public_html/dashboard/beheer.php on line 133

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in /home/xxxxxxxx/domains/xxxxxx.nl/public_html/dashboard/beheer.php on line 133
```

The dbconfig

```
 dbconfig.php
    <?php
    class Database
    {

        private $host = "localhost";
        private $db_name = "xxxxxx";
        private $username = "xxxxxx";
        private $password = "xxxxxx!";
        public $conn;

        public function dbConnection()
        {

            $this->conn = null;    
            try
            {
                $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
                $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
            }
            catch(PDOException $exception)
            {
                echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
            }

            return $this->conn;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Exactly what is says, $connect is not defined, which means you probably forgot to open the database connection.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$r` instead of `$d` in `$d = $connect->query("...");` ?

Comment: @e4c5 Aah, and how can I open that connection. (sorry I just begon yesterday ghehe)

Comment: @LGson I dont have any idea. I changed it but the same error came up.

Comment: @Willem-Jelle you will have to look up on tutorials for php mysqli. specifically for connecting to database you need to use mysqli_connect()

Comment: @Hallur the page is connected to class.user.php who is connect do config.php and the other things work, only this thing does not work. Or isnt that what you are meaning?..

Comment: if you posted your config.php and expanded your current snippet to show how it's included. Someone might be able to help

Comment: @e4c5 I will :)

Comment: @all This has been fixed. No idea how, but a friend of mine fixed it..